# Extend user access token in Keycloak with external data

Tags: jwt, keycloak

We use the Keycloak service as SSO solution and provide the resulting JWT to different microservices and that works very well.

But now we have the problem that the JWT must be extended with data from an external resource when the user tries to login.

More tangible, a user has access to different markets with an unique ID as identifier, but we didn't see the management which user have access to which market inside the Keycloak service.

What could be the best solution for this problem?
After reading the docs an custom User Storage SPI is an answer, but I think that is a little bit to much..

As information we use Keycloak 3.1.0 as a standalone service with an postgres DB

Answer (score 2):

The way you add extra data/information to your keycloak JWT token payloads, comes by means of adding  "client-scopes" configured with the proper **protocol mappers** within them, that allows you to add any amount of custom extra information to your Id-token and access-token.

One example of this, would be having extra variables in your users, and then in the protocol mappers within the (newly-created) "client-scope", you can add a protocol-mappers of type "User-Attribute", so that your specific user variable will appear in your token the way you configured on your "protocol-mapper". There are many types of "protocol mappers" that'll allow you to map diverse type information to your tokens (is not just for mapping user variables).

This was addressed  on this question before:

[Keycloak User Storage SPI Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477346/keycloak-user-storage-spi-implementation/57520791#57520791)

I'm copying here the part which is relevant to you:

Origianl question was:

*[How to]"Retrieve some attributes from external datasource, map it to keycloak's id and access token. Need to retrieve users unique id and add it as subject id in the jwt. That's the id, rest of the services can use to retrieve the id, when this token is passed to other services."*

[Answer:]

**For this, the best you can do is:
Add those user's unique data as users attributes (see them on the Admin console)
Create a "Client scope" on Keycloak, with a corresponding mapper of type "user property" to map each of those values you'd like to add (from your user data) to your Id-token and access-token. You also need to tie your client with your just created "client scope". This may sound a little bit confusing, but this video is great material and I bilieve it'll help you alot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxpY_zZ52kU (arround min 6:30 you'll see how to add extra user info to your tokens)**