# get Id ( not clientId) from keycloak jwt token

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, clientid

JWT only gives the user information and clientId, how can I get ID of the client as shown in the image

I CAN GET CLIENT DETAILS PARTICULARLY **ID** FROM THIS URL
**https://${SERVER_URL}/auth/admin/realms/master/clients?clientId=test**

**API RESPONSE**

```
  {
    "id": "12af651d-f6fe-49ef-8e6f-b951a49ff7db", // want to add this id into JWT
    "clientId": "test",
    "rootUrl": "${authBaseUrl}", ......
}
```

but I want to save my api call for getting Id

> How can I get client information "Id" within jwt?
> Now this is showing on the extraction of jwt

```
{
  exp: 1627981808,
  iat: 1627974608,
  sub: '923666de-0b37-42f0-b694-0491028d0b78', // user Id
  typ: 'Bearer',
  azp: 'test', // client id 
  acr: '1',
  scope: 'openid email profile',
  email_verified: false,
  name: 'name123',
  preferred_username: 'name123',
  given_name: 'name123',
  email: 'any_name@gmail.com'
}
```

Any help/information will be helpful for me.

Comment: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html - you can use admin REST API to create client/mappers

Answer (score 0):

You should create and deploy a SPI to your keycloak instance. That's a JAR that overrides standard behaviour. There are various SPIs both described in the documentation and as code in GitHub keycloak repo.
With that SPI you can add just about anything to your token. I would suggest not to change anything that exists in the default token as this might impact your OID compatibility.

See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521333/extend-user-access-token-in-keycloak-with-external-data) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477346/keycloak-user-storage-spi-implementation/57520791#57520791).

Comment: Why standard mappers can't be used? In theory the claim with static client uuid can be added via mappers. That will be only client config change, so no custom SPI development/deployment will be needed.

Comment: @JanGaraj your solution might work for me, can you please elaborate more on how can I achieve that, thanks

Comment: @TanzeelSaleem https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_protocol-mappers - create new mapper of used client `Mapper Type: Hardcoded claim` and configure rest options for your need - that's very naive/simple solution. Javali's solution is also valid, but it's very advanced.

Comment: @JanGaraj great it's working. But I need to add this mapper manually. Can be this automate by any source ? when the client created its Hardcoded claim also add in mapper? do they have any Api for this?